# How to give the @model inside the view a value of 2 lists in ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

None of the solution I have found so far on the internet work for me.

How do I give this `@model` inside the view a value of 2 lists?

```
@using BusnLogicLaag
@model List<Outfit>
```

I also want to add a list: `List<Onderdeel>`.

These are my two classes:

```
/// <summary>
/// Onderdeel heeft unieke categorien, ook heeft deze een ID
/// Bij een onderdeel horen ook bepaalde reviews
/// </summary>
public class Onderdeel : Kleding
{
    public enum OnderdeelCategory
    {
        Broek,
        Shirt,
        Bloes,
        Schoen,
        Jurk
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; } = new List<Review>();
    public OnderdeelCategory DeCategory { get; }

    public Onderdeel(int id, string titel, int prijs, OnderdeelCategory category, string fileAdress) : base(titel, prijs, fileAdress)
    {
        DeCategory = category;
        this.ID = id;
    }
    
    public Onderdeel(OnderdeelDTO dto) : base(dto.Titel, dto.Prijs, dto.FileAdress)
    {
        DeCategory = (Onderdeel.OnderdeelCategory)dto.DeCategory;
        this.ID = dto.ID;
    }        

    internal OnderdeelDTO GetDTO()
    {
        OnderdeelDTO dto = new OnderdeelDTO(ID, Titel, Prijs, (OnderdeelDTO.OnderdeelCategory)DeCategory, FileAdress);
        return dto;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + $"\nCategory: {DeCategory}";
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Outfit heeft unieke categorien
/// Outfit heeft ook een ID en bij een outfit kunnen meerdere reviews horen
/// </summary>
public class Outfit : Kleding
{
    public enum OutfitCategory
    {
        Trendy,
        Chic,
        Oldschool,
        Casual
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public OutfitCategory DeCategory { get; set; }

    public Outfit(int id, string titel, int prijs, OutfitCategory category, string fileAdress) : base(titel, prijs, fileAdress)
    {
        DeCategory = category;
        this.ID = id;
    }

    public Outfit(OutfitDTO dto) : base(dto.Titel, dto.Prijs, dto.FileAdress)
    {
        DeCategory = (Outfit.OutfitCategory)dto.DeCategory;
        ID = dto.ID;
    }

    internal OutfitDTO GetDTO()
    {
         OutfitDTO dto = new OutfitDTO(ID, Titel, Prijs, (OutfitDTO.OutfitCategory)DeCategory, FileAdress);
         return dto;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + $"\nCategory: {DeCategory}";
    }
}
```

The namespaces for both of them is `BusnLogicLaag`.

So the point is to give that view access to 2 lists of objects, these objects are `Onderdeel` and `Outfit`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new ViewModel to wrap `Onderdeel` and `Outfit` and then use this ViewModel directly in the view.

Below is my test code:

Onderdeel:

```
public class Onderdeel 
{
        public enum OnderdeelCategory
        {
            Broek,
            Shirt,
            Bloes,
            Schoen,
            Jurk
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Outfit:

```
public class Outfit 
{
        public enum OutfitCategory
        {
            Trendy,
            Chic,
            Oldschool,
            Casual
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class TestModel
{
        public List<Outfit> outfits { get; set; }
        public List<Onderdeel> onderdeels { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Test()
{
            List<Onderdeel> onderdeel = new List<Onderdeel>();
            onderdeel.Add(new Onderdeel { ID = 1 });
            onderdeel.Add(new Onderdeel { ID = 2 });
            onderdeel.Add(new Onderdeel { ID = 3 });

            List<Outfit> outfits = new List<Outfit>();
            outfits.Add(new Outfit { ID = 4 });
            outfits.Add(new Outfit { ID = 5 });
            outfits.Add(new Outfit { ID = 6 });

            var viewmodel = new TestModel
            {
                onderdeels = onderdeel,
                outfits = outfits
            };

            return View(viewmodel);
}
```

View:

```
@using _2022053001.Models
@model TestModel

<div>
    @foreach(var item in Model.onderdeels)
    {
        <div>@item.ID</div>
        <select class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Onderdeel.OnderdeelCategory>()"></select>
    }
</div>

<div>
    @foreach(var item in Model.outfits)
    {
        <div>@item.ID</div>
        <select class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Outfit.OutfitCategory>()"></select>
    }
</div>
```

Test Result:
[image]